# How to hide subheadings from powerpoint presentation (when in show mode)?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, slideshow

I have a slide containing text:

1. This is a heading

   - this is a subheading
   - this is a subheading
2. This is a heading

   - this ia a subheading
   - this is a subheading

When putting this slide on show, I would like to show only the headings 1. and 2. and keep the subheadings permanently hidden. How to achieve this? I need all of the text in handouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using custom animation as follows

- Select the 1st heading and its sub headings
- Choose Add Effect -> Entrance -> Appear
- Select just the sub-headings under heading 1
- Choose Add Effect -> Exit -> Disappear
- In the custom animation list right click on the the just added "disappear" items and choose "Start with Previous"

Repeat.

The custom animations will not effect the handouts so the sub-headings should print.